# Appending using MQFTE?

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

Is it possible to append the contents of a file to another file.

EG: Test.txt and Result.txt has some data.

I need to append the contents of Test.txt with result.txt.

Is this possible in MQFTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.  Assuming Test.txt already exists at the destination, you can transfer result.txt and then use Ant or a Post-Transfer Call to concatenate the two files.

For example, transfer the file to a staging directory and then use a post-transfer call to execute:
`cat ${file} >> ../final/directory/Test.txt; rm ${file}`

Since the post-transfer call is part of the transfer, the results will be captured in the FTE status message at completion of the transfer.